# How to count individual user selections in a while loop

Tags: java

I would like to know how to count the number of times a user selects a specific option within a while loop. The user is selecting location, and I need to keep track of how many times this location is selected. What's the best way to do this without using an array? For example, I want to keep track of each time the while loop processes, how many London, Rome, or Key West options are selected.

```
locationSelection = mainMenu(console);
while (locationSelection != 'Q') {
    if(locationSelection == 'A') { 
        locationSelectionString = "London, England.";
    }
    if (locationSelection == 'B') { 
        locationSelectionString = "Rome, Italy.";
    }
    if (locationSelection == 'C') { 
        locationSelectionString = "Key West, Florida.";
    }
    if (locationSelection == 'Q') {
        break;
    }
```

Comment: Without arrays? `numLondon++`, `numRome++`, etc...

Comment: That doesn't really help me, doesn't tell me where to place those in the code. I'm hopelessly confused about how to do it...

Comment: Make a number that starts at zero. Call it numberofRomes. If you detect Rome, add 1 to numberOfRomes. Repeat for the other two. It is just simple counting.

Comment: It's irrelevant but if you use switch or if-else instead of these if statements, conditions after the one matched are not evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

Simply declare a counter.

```
int counter = 0;
```

then inside your if statements increase the counter.

```
int counterA = 0;
int counterB = 0;
int counterC = 0;
locationSelection = mainMenu(console);
while (locationSelection != 'Q') {
    if(locationSelection == 'A') { 
        locationSelectionString = "London, England.";
        counterA++;
    }
    if (locationSelection == 'B') { 
        locationSelectionString = "Rome, Italy.";
        counterB++;
    }
    if (locationSelection == 'C') { 
        locationSelectionString = "Key West, Florida.";
        counterC++;
    }
    if (locationSelection == 'Q') {
        break;
    }
```

Comment: I've done that, but the issue I'm running into is when I try to print the accumulated values AFTER the entire loop has ended (with user selecting 'Q'), the report has no value for it.

Comment: I posted it above. Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: @DonovanGatlin the report has no value? How do you retrieve the counter, can you post your approach so we can reproduce it?

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.printf("Total London Vacations: %d", counterLondon);
System.out.printf("Total Rome Vacations: %d", counterRome );
System.out.printf("Total Key West Vacations: %d", counterKeyWest );
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.